# My JFrame shows up after running a "while" loop. I want the JFrame to show while it's running

Tags: java, android, swing, sockets, serversocket

what's up guys. I'm having a problem here. The file is running but there are logical errors. I connected my android app to this java app. I'm trying to send multiple messages in a list of a JFrame, it shows, but it's not showing while the JFrame is running. It goes like this

(JFRAME STILL NOT SHOWING)I connect to java app

(JFRAME STILL NOT SHOWING)Send some messages, it shows in println
Then after i close my android app

JFrame shows up from java app with the messages i sent.(The messages are stored in a JList)

I want it to be like, while the JFrame is showing, i want the values in Jlist to append. Please see this code. This is the code im using

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JList;


public class frmTestList extends JFrame {
public static final int portNumber = 60123;
private JPanel contentPane;
 static String data;
 static DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

             frmTestList frame = new frmTestList();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                try {


                     ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                       while((data = br.readLine()) != null ){

                        System.out.println("Message from the client: " + data);
                        model.addElement(data);
                       }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public frmTestList() {


    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JList list = new JList(model);
    contentPane.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);


}




}
```

Android Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Socket socket = null;
public String debuggingString = "DEBUG";
public String hostname = ""; // <-- my ipv4 is here
public int portNumber = 60123;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                //connecting
                Log.e(debuggingString, "Attempting to connect to server");
                socket = new Socket(hostname, portNumber);

                //Send message to server
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                bw.write("this is a message from the client");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();

                //Receive message from server
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                System.out.println("Message from server: " + br.readLine());
            } catch (
                    Exception e
                    )

            {
                Log.e(debuggingString, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }.start();
}

;

public void sendMessage(View v) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    BufferedWriter bw = null;

    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        bw.write(editText.getText().toString());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(debuggingString, e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Side note: ClassNames go UpperCase in Java. So, frmTestList is simply a bad name!

Comment: Hint: please let us know if my simple suggestion already worked out.

Comment: Thank you for the Side Note, @GhostCat. But the solution you suggested is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: after further thinking, I am guessing: your problem could be

A) that your server sits there and waits for input from the client. Meaning: it loops on "new input" ... probably until it the client **closes** the connection.

and/or

B) that your "server" tries to update the UI within the same thread that accepts. So, try:

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
 String line = null;
 while( (line = br.readLine() ) != null) {
   System.out.println("Message from server: " + br.readLine());
   EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
      model.addElement(line);
   }
```

Finally: if those ideas dont work out; you should step back - by making your setup easier (by taking Android out of the picture): create the client socket within your JFrame and have that one process be client/server at the same time. This will make debugging/experimenting much easier. Only when that works, move the client ... into another JVM, and then to "Android".

In other words: step back, and start with a very simple Client/Server test that does everything in one class. When that works, move on.

Comment: Hello, @GhostCat! I tried your suggested solution. But it's still not working the way how I want it. Thanks, though!

Comment: Well "not working the way I want it" doesn't say if/what changed by making that change. Which would be required, if you want us to provide other ideas.

Comment: Yes, of course GhostCat! I would love to test other ideas from you. This is the current state flow of my program now.

(Jframe is showing) Java app runs
(Jframe is showing) Sending messages on java app from android app
After i close my android app, The list updates the messages i sent. 

I want the program to work like this

(Jframe is showing) I send messages on java app from android app then changes the list values at the moment i click the button from android app.

Comment: That makes room for some thoughts; please see my updated answer. If that doesn't help ... you should update your question and provide the "android" side of things in detail, too - at least that "socket writing" code.

Comment: Hello, GhostCat! I'm sorry if you have to make so many suggestions. I'm just a newbie here in StackOverflow! But I thank you for that! Please see my updated post. I already provided the android code. Thank you!

Comment: Dont worry, thats my choice. And as you can see; I overlooked that Android part ... that code looks ok from what I can see. The only thing that seems strange: your client seems to wait for an answer from the server; but the server is not sending anything? What happens when you remove that "waiting for an answer".

Comment: Dont mind. We stop the discussion now. I updated the answer (again ;-); and I hope that gets you going. If not, you can still put up another comment; and we will see then.

Comment: Finally: and in case you get things working to my input, feel free to accept answer; preferably **tomorrow**; as I already hit the 200-cap for today ;-)

Comment: Hello, GhostCat! It's working now! This is so great! But there is another problem now. It works, but it takes 2 button clicks before the server receives the message from the client. I'm still going to make this one answered.

Sure, GhostCat! I will accept your answer first thing tomorrow!

Comment: Never mind, GhostCat! I already fixed the new problem! Thanks and this is so great! I will mark this one answered!

Sure, GhostCat! I will accept your answer first thing tomorrow!

Comment: Thanks for keeping your promise. That is kinda uplifting today; as I just ran into a newbie who thinks me telling him that he gave a bad answer ... and now he is serial-downvoting my stuff. That wont last, but still annoying. So, thanks for the uplift!

Comment: Don't mind it, GhostCat. You seriously helped me with the hours i spent just to figure this out. And seeing your profile, it really shows you have the talent. Thanks and good luck on your career

Answer (score 0):

The reason your JFrame is not displaying is because your performing all your socket reading from the Event Dispatching Thread. Doing this will lock up all UI updates. Move your socket reading actions to its own Thread and call invokeLater when updating the JList model.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    frmTestList frame = new frmTestList();

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             try {
                 ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
                 Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                 while((data = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                     EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                         public void run() {
                             model.addElement(data);
                         }
                     });
                 }
             } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             } 
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

Comment: Hello, @eighthrazz! GhostCat's answer already worked for me. But thank you for providing another solution. I hope other people will benefit from the solution you provided! Thank you!